# Mostrar dato concreto de array

Tags: php

Quiero mostrar un dato concreto de un array, tengo el siguiente código y estoy intentando que la función `imprimirAlumnoConcreto` me imprima un alumno concreto que yo le indique pasada por la variable `$nombre`.

```
$alumnos = array();

function imprimirAlumnoConcreto($nombre) {

    foreach($this->alumnos['nombre'] as $key=>$value){
        echo $value->getNombre() . " ";
        echo $value->getApellido() . " ";

    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Pero dónde están los datos y cómo están estructurados? Pon un ejemplo de la estructura de datos donde se debe buscar el nombre.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $alumnos = array(

    "alumno" => array("nombre" => "Juan","apellido" => "M"),
    array("nombre" => "Mario","apellido" => "C"), 
    array("nombre" => "Carlos","apellido" => "G"),
    array("nombre" => "Perla","apellido" => "S"),

);


function imprimirAlumnoConcreto($array,$nombre) 
{

    foreach($array as $value)
    {
        if($value["nombre"] == $nombre)
        {
            $result = $value["nombre"]." ".$value["apellido"];
        }


    }

    return $result;
}


echo imprimirAlumnoConcreto($alumnos,"Carlos");
```

algo así creo que te funcionaria